# row index in gridview rowCommand

Tags: asp.net

Just want to transfer value from variable to nother variable :

```
 protected void gvVariableDetail_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
            {

                 int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                 GridViewRow gvRow = gvVariableConfig.Rows[index];
                 int rowIndex = index;

            }

        }
```

But rowindex still have zero value, and index got row value(in these case i try edit row 2 and so index value is 1(start by 0)). so hope anyone know how to transfer index value to rowIndex.

Comment: That's cool you want to do that, but what is your question?

Comment: need to get row index for use with javascript, but i want to trigger those script by button, not by one of command in grid. so i want to transfer index value to global variable, to use by another button

Comment: A perfectly good response that still contains no questions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use the `CommandSource` property and cast it's [`NamingContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx) to the `GridViewRow`. Then you can use it's `RowIndex` property:

```
GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer; 
int rowIndex    = gvr.RowIndex;
```

If you want to use the `CommandArgument` you have to set it from aspx:

```
CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>'
```

then this also works:

```
int RowIndex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
```

Comment: got message Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ContentPlaceHolder' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'.

Comment: using approach 1 sir. i am using control in extended grid view to trigger RowCommand

Comment: i am newbie to asp so i will just post the code...
protected void gvVariableDetail_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
           
            if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
            {

                ...........
                
            }
            
        }

using last solution can't do it because convert string to int