# GridView Delete Row

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable

I'm trying to delete a row in a gridview (the data is not in the database yet), so it should be a simple delete row, if anybody can please point me in the right direction....
This is what I have done:

```
     else if (e.CommandName == "DeletePart")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); //#1 line
        GridView1.DeleteRow(index);  //#2 line
    }
```

The error that I am receiving is : "Input string was not in a correct format." (this happens on #1 line)...

This is how the gridview looks like: (use a linkbutton to do the delete)

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  AllowPaging="True" 
                                EmptyDataText="No parts has been added to the model, please add a part."
                                BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid"  BorderWidth="2px" 
                                CellPadding="3" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
                            onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" onrowdeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting">
                                <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" CssClass="EditButton" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                                 </ItemTemplate>
                                 </asp:TemplateField>
                                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CssClass="DeleteButton" CommandName="DeletePart" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' Text="Delete" />
                                 </ItemTemplate>
                                 </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC"  BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" 
                                BorderWidth="2px" />
                        </asp:GridView>
```

Class of how the gridview populated and binded:

```
     public int companyID = 0;
public int methodID = 0;
DataTable dt;
#region SQLConnections

string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SOSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection conn;
#endregion

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        MakeDataTable();
        EmptyDataString();
    }
    else
    {
        dt = (DataTable)ViewState["DataTable"];
    }
    ViewState["DataTable"] = dt; 

}

#region GridView

private void EmptyDataString()
{
    TemplateBuilder tmpEmptyDataTemplate = new TemplateBuilder();
    tmpEmptyDataTemplate.AppendLiteralString("No parts has been added to the model, please add a part.");
    GridView1.EmptyDataTemplate = tmpEmptyDataTemplate;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

private void MakeDataTable()
{
    dt.Columns.Add("Item");
    dt.Columns.Add("Quantity");
    dt.Columns.Add("Price P/Quantity");
}

private void AddToDataTable()
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Item"] = txtPart.Text;
    dr["Quantity"] = numQuantity.Text;
    dr["Price P/Quantity"] = txtPricePQ.Text;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}

private void BindGrid()
{
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void btnAddPart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddToDataTable();
    BindGrid();
    ClearNewParts();
}
#endregion

    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
            txtPart.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
            numQuantity.Text = row.Cells[3].Text;
            txtPricePQ.Text = row.Cells[4].Text;
        }
    }
    else if (e.CommandName == "DeletePart")
    {
        //int iCount = GridView1.Rows.Count;
        //for (int i = 1; i <= iCount; i++)
        //{
        //    GridView1.DeleteRow(i);
        //}
      //  int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.SelectedRow);

        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridView1.DeleteRow(index);

        //int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        //GridView1.DeleteRow(rowIndex);
    }


    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Could you debug it and show the value of e.CommandArgument?

Comment: It breaks on that specific line and if I look at the value it's giving only this "" ... Is there another way to delete a row?

Comment: Have you tried `GridView1.SelectedIndex` to get the index of the deleted row?

Comment: @noobob, the int rowIndex = GridView1.SelectedIndex; brings back -1, yes I have tried that...

Comment: @user2042152 where is the databounded..

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285918/row-index-in-gridview-rowcommand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution, only needed to do a databound.... Here is the working code:

```
    else if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {     
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridView1.DeleteRow(index);
        ((DataTable)ViewState["DataTable"]).Rows[index].Delete();
        ((DataTable)ViewState["DataTable"]).AcceptChanges();
        GridView1.DataSource = (DataTable)ViewState["Data"];
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: no need to write `GridView1.DeleteRow(index);` if you are assigning final `ViewState["DataTable"]'` to your Gridview.

Answer (score 1):

> Seems like you didn't mention `CommandArgument` property in the `GridView`.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv" 
              CommandName="DeletePart" 
              CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'>         
</asp:GridView>
```

> Add the `CommandArgument` as shown above.

Comment: Adding the CommandArgument works for the gridview, but I'm still not getting back the rowindex that sould be deleted....

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

**In ASPX**:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="Gridview1" CommandName="delete" CommandArgument='<%#Container.DataItem.Index %>'/>
```

**Cs**:

```
else if (e.CommandName == "DeletePart")
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); 
    GridView1.DeleteRow(index);
}
```

Comment: the index is returned as 0... the row still doesn't delete from the gridview.....

Comment: @user2042152 where is the data to delete? u doesn't bind anything in gridview then how can u delete a row?

Comment: When the row is inserted it is binded to the gridview, will update my post for you to see

Comment: I am not able to get this Container.DataItem.Index.

Answer (score 0):

try int.TryParse , this will solve the input string fromat problem , but why is it occuring that you need to check the CommandArgument you are setting.

```
else if (e.CommandName == "DeletePart")
{
    int index =-1;
    if(int.TryParse(e.CommandArgument,out index)) //#1 line
        GridView1.DeleteRow(index);  //#2 line
}
```

Comment: the e.CommandArgument will always be empty since he just created the row.

Comment: i am showing the correct way of parsing , actual problem lies somewhere else that i already mentioned

Comment: This method gets another error: "The best overloaded method match for 'int.TryParse(string, out int)' has some invalid arguments", The reason I am trying to get the CommandArgument is because I need to get the rowindex.... I've looked at a few sites on the internet and found that this was the most used way to delete a row.... Thanks maybe just need to get another way of getting the index....

Answer (score 0):

```
Thy This:) 

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  CssClass="gridview"
                            HorizontalAlign="Left" PagerSettings-Visible="true" AllowPaging="True" 
                            PageSize ="5" Width="300px" >
                            <Columns>
                               <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ButtonType="Button" />      
                            </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>

then code behinde:


    Protected Sub GridView1_RowDeleting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDeleting
        DirectCast(ViewState("CurrentDataReference"), DataTable).Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex)
        GridView1.DataSource = DirectCast(ViewState("CurrentDataReference"), DataTable)
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Sub
```