# removing rows from datagridview after insert them to database

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, c#-3.0

I wrote a program that insert barcode of different things to database.
First of all I add all barcodes to a datagridview after if user click to a button all barcodes insert to database from datagridview.

before each barcode inserts to database i check it for duplicates.

I want to remove each barcode from datagridview when each of them inserts to database .

but it doesn't work correctly

it just insert some of them to databse and some of them aer left in datagrid view 
here is its code :

```
         Cnn.Open();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("select BarcodeId from Bought_Product where BarcodeId='" + row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "'", Cnn);
            SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
               {
                   MessageBox.Show(dr[0].ToString() + "تکراری می باشد");

               }
               dr.Close();
            }
            else
            {

                dr.Close();
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into Bought_Product (Persons_Id,Bought_Date,Bought_fac_num,BarcodeId) values ('" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox1.Text + "','" + row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "')", Cnn);
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show(row.ToString());
                dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
            }
        }
        Cnn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: If you want all the rows to be removed once the foreach has completed just call `dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();` after the loop has completed. Your call to `dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);` will fail anyway because you are modifying the collection you are iterating over.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403231/gridview-delete-row

Comment: You might also want to [parametrize](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Query_Parameterization_Cheat_Sheet)  your SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem 2 day´s ago... 
Actually my programm doing fine. May this helps you:

```
            if (MessageBox.Show("Delete this Row?", "Löschen", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
              if (!this.dataGridView1.Rows[this.rowIndex].IsNewRow)
              {
                this.dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(this.rowIndex);
              }

            }
```