# Index out of range while getting Gridview selected row value in Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

I'm trying to get the values of a `GridView` selected row in sessions through a button field in the GridView but its giving me a `Index out of range` error at:

```
GridViewRow row = AdminSearchGridView.Rows[index]
```

**Note: There is only one row in the GridView currently from which I want to select the values I want.**

code for GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="AdminSearchGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
Style="color: #333333; border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 14px; text-align: center;
width: 1530px; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"
AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowDeleting="AdminSearchGridView_RowDeleting"
OnRowCommand="AdminSearchGridView_RowCommand">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

    <Columns>
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="Issue" CommandName="Issue" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="IssueStatus" HeaderText="Issue Status" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AccessionNo" HeaderText="Accession Number" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CallNo" HeaderText="Call Number" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" />
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

And Code Behind is...

```
protected void AdminSearchGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName == "Issue")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        GridViewRow row = AdminSearchGridView.Rows[index]; // INDEX OUT OF RANGE ERROR OCCURS HERE

        string accessno = AdminSearchGridView.Rows[index].Cells[3].Text;
        string title = AdminSearchGridView.Rows[index].Cells[5].Text;
        string author = AdminSearchGridView.Rows[index].Cells[6].Text;

        Session["accessno"] = accessno;
        Session["title"] = title;
        Session["author"] = author;
    }
}
```

I checked that the `e.CommandArgument` is returning an int value 0 but 
i cannot figure out what is going wrong since `AdminSearchGridView.Rows[0]` makes sense as there is a row in the GridView then why Index out of range?

Comment: sorry the author stuff is there but its not part of the question.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285918/row-index-in-gridview-rowcommand

Comment: i see you have defined columns for the gridview but no rows.

Comment: check for the index value that whether that Rows count > 0

Comment: do you need to add <rows> </rows> to the gridview

Comment: thanks for your response. I found out later that everything was alright except that the gridview datasource was set to null on page load. Consequently the gridview after pageload had rows null so the index got out of range. and the Cells index was a thing occuring later in time so the error was infact at the AdminSearchGridView.Rows[index] due to the datasource set to null on page load

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that the Index out of range error is not coming from the line what you have marked. However it is coming from the following line

```
string author = AdminSearchGridView.Rows[index].Cells[6].Text;
```

By looking at your ASPX code, there are 5 columns declared and there is also 
AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" which adds one more column. Which means there are total 6 columns, so AdminSearchGridView.Rows[index].Cells[6].Text must give index out of bound exception. Can you comment this line and check if this solves the problem?

Comment: thanks for your response Kiran.  I found out later that everything was alright except that the gridview datasource was set to null on page load. Consequently the gridview after pageload had rows null so the index got out of range. and the Cells index was a thing occuring later in time so the error was infact at the AdminSearchGridView.Rows[index] due to the datasource set to null on page load